# Query is taking a long time to complete

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have the following query where depending on the site name (afield1) value different columns are used to get PatrolNo information. the query is fetching data for the current week starting from sunday from a view, and then building the count for each site.

but it takes a lot of time to return values.

```
select cast(temp.timetag1 as date) as Date, temp.PatrolNo,temp.ScansDue, COUNT(*) as Total,temp.aField1
from (select timetag1, afield1 ,
case when afield1 = 'site1' then afield17
when afield1 = 'site2' then afield16
when afield1 = 'site3' then afield18
when afield1 = 'site4' then afield19
when afield1 = 'site5' then afield20
when afield1 = 'site6' then afield21
when afield1 = 'site7' then afield22 end as PatrolNo,
case when afield1 = 'site1' then 17
when afield1 = 'site2' then 8
when afield1 = 'site3' then 9
when afield1 = 'site4' then 32
when afield1 = 'site5' then 15
when afield1 = 'site6' then 15
when afield1 = 'site7' then 52 end as ScansDue
FROM         someview
where timetag1 >= (dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53690,getdate()-1)/7)*7,-53690))  and timetag1 < GETDATE()
and aField1 like 'site2'
and (afield3 like '%SER%' OR afield10 like '%SER%' OR afield11 like '%SER%' OR afield12 like '%SER%' OR afield13 like '%SER%' 
OR afield14 like '%SER%' OR afield15 like '%SER%')
    ) temp
group by cast(temp.timetag1 as date),aField1, PatrolNo,ScansDue;

date            PatrolNo    ScansDue  Total    aField1
2014-07-21      1           32        63       site1
2014-07-21      2           32        63       site2
2014-07-21      3           32        32       site1
2014-07-21      4           32        31       site7
2014-07-21      5           32        30       site7
```

Comment: Have you checked the usual suspects i.e. whether you have indexes on the columns used for filtering and grouping?

Comment: You should also consider normalizing this table. How many afields are there? How do you handle adding a new one? This should be a second table instead of whole list of columns.

Comment: Are you sure you need wildcards at the beginning?IF not an index becomes possible.

Comment: i had to use like statements because i am only considering the rows where the mentioned field values starting with SER. ill remove wildcard operator for checking for site2. but not too sure if i can make any other changes

Comment: if it's only starting with SER then at least only do 'SER%' instead of '%SER%'. That should help a bit

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your query is taking a long time because of the LIKE statements in your Where clause. The way they are being used will prevent any indexes from being used. For example, %SER% will prevent any index from being used. A scan must be done. And, of course, I would also guess you have a large number of rows in your table(s).

And, as a suggestion, [aField1 like 'site2'] doesn't make any sense. No reason to use LIKE here since you're not using any wildcard characters.

What you should do, as a general practice, is to take your query, generate the estimated query plan (in SSMS for example), and look for scans in the plan. This is often a red flag for performance.

Comment: i had to use like statements because i am only considering the rows where the mentioned field values starting with SER. ill remove wildcard operator for checking for site2. but not too sure if i can make any other changes

Comment: You may not be able to. But, just keep in mind that when you use LIKE the way you are (%SER%), and index cannot be used.

Comment: @HakanZim - if it's only starting with SER then at least only do 'SER%' instead of '%SER%'. That should help a bit.